# Plot result from the function of NDSolve

Tags: plotting

I have a solution that I got from NDSolve which are ua and uw.

```
eq1=Derivative[2, 0][uw][z, t]*cwv-Derivative[0,1][ua][z,t]*cw == Derivative[0, 1][uw][z, t];
eq2=Derivative[2, 0][ua][z, t]*cav-Derivative[0,1][uw][z,t]*ca == Derivative[0, 1][ua][z, t];

ic1 = {uw[zmax, t] == ui + p0, uw[z, tmin] == ui};
ic2 = {ua[z, tmin] == uatm};
sol2 = NDSolve[Flatten[{eq1, eq2, ic1, ic2}], {uw, ua}, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin,
 tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> dt/step, InterpolationOrder -> All];

result = (ua[z, t] /. sol2) - (atm[z, t]) - (uw[z, t] /. sol2);
```

I manage to solve this equation and I can plot "result" by using Plot3D.

```
Plot3D[result, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
       PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t, "result"[z, t]}, 
       BoundaryStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 500]
```

However, I also wants to plot this equation by using manipulate command in Plot but I failed. Here is how I do it

```
Manipulate[Plot[result, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, 
                AxesLabel -> {t, "result"[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]
```

or by using this code

```
Manipulate[result[z,t], {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, 
           AxesLabel -> {t, "result"[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]
```

Can someone please tell me how to plot "result" by using manipulate command?I can do it for each ua[z,t] and uw[z,t]

For the complete set of code

```
kw = 1*10^(-10);(*m/s*)
ka = 8*10^(-13);(*m/s*)
gw = 10;(*kN/m^3*)
m2w = 2.41*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility of water phase with respect to matric suction*)
m1w = 0.8*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility of water phase with respect to axial stress*)
m2a = 1.11*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility with air phase with respect to matric suction*)
m1a = 0.37*10^(-4);(*coefficient of compressibility of air phase with respect to axial stress*)
p0 = 100;(*applied pressure -kPa*)
tmin = 0;(*minimum or time when the pressure is applied*)
tmax = 5000;(*latest inspected time*)
zmin = 0;(*top elevation*)
zmax = 0.02;(*bottom elevation*)
uatm = 101;(*kPa-atmospheric air pressure*)
step = 1000;(*The higher the step, the higher the accuracy*)
ui = -400;(*Initial matric suction*)

temp = 300;(*temperature in kelvin*)
wa = 28.97;(*kg/kmol*)
s = 0.7887;
n = 1.0696/(1 + 1.0696);
(*CALCULATION*)
r = 8.31432;(*Universal gas constant in j/(mol K*)
g = 9.8;(*gravity acceleration-m2/s*)
da = ka/g;(*function varies with matric suction, havent been defined yet*)
cwv = kw/(gw*m2w);
cw = ((1 - m2w/m1w)/(m2w/m1w));
ca = (m2a/m1a)/(1 - (m2a/m1a) - (1 - s)*n/(uatm*m1a));
cav = (da/(wa/(r*temp)*uatm))/(m1a*(1 - m2a/m1a) - (1 - s)*n);
dt = tmax - tmin;

eq1 = Derivative[2, 0][uw][z, t]*cwv - Derivative[0, 1][ua][z, t]*cw == Derivative[0, 1][uw][z, t];
eq2 = Derivative[2, 0][ua][z, t]*cav - Derivative[0, 1][uw][z, t]*ca == Derivative[0, 1][ua][z, t];

ic1 = {uw[zmax, t] == ui + p0, uw[z, tmin] == ui};
ic2 = {ua[z, tmin] == uatm};
sol2 = NDSolve[Flatten[{eq1, eq2, ic1, ic2}], {uw, ua}, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin,tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> dt/step, InterpolationOrder -> All];

Column[Plot3D[uw[z, t] /. sol2, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t, uw[z, t]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 500], Plot3D[ua[z, t] /. sol2, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t, ua[z, t]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 500]]

Column[Manipulate[Plot[uw[z, t] /. sol2, {z, zmin, zmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {z, uw[z, t]}], {t, tmin, tmax}],Manipulate[Plot[uw[z, t] /. sol2, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {t, uw[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]]

Column[Manipulate[Plot[ua[z, t] /. sol2, {z, zmin, zmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {z, ua[z, t]}], {t, tmin, tmax}],Manipulate[Plot[ua[z, t] /. sol2, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {t, ua[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]]

Column[Manipulate[Plot[{uw[z, tmin] /. sol2, uw[z, t1] /. sol2, uw[z, t2] /. sol2, uw[z, t3] /. sol2, uw[z, t4] /. sol2, uw[z, tmax] /. sol2}, {z, zmin, zmax}, AxesLabel -> {z, uw[z, t]}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {z, uw[z, t]}], {t1, tmin + dt/1000, tmin + dt/51}, {t2, tmin + dt/50, tmin + dt/16}, {t3, tmin + dt/15,tmin + dt/3}, {t4, tmin + dt/3, tmin + dt/1}], Manipulate[Plot[{ua[z, tmin] /. sol2, ua[z, t1] /. sol2, ua[z, t2] /. sol2, ua[z, t3] /. sol2, ua[z, t4] /. sol2, ua[z, tmax] /. sol2}, {z, zmin, zmax}, AxesLabel -> {z, ua[z, t]}, PlotRange -> Full], {t1, tmin + dt/500, tmin + dt/51}, {t2, tmin + dt/50, tmin + dt/16}, {t3, tmin + dt/15, tmin + dt/3}, {t4, tmin + dt/3, tmin + dt/1}]]

atm[z, t] = uatm
result == (ua[z, t] /. sol2) - (atm[z, t]) - (uw[z, t] /. sol2);
Plot3D[result, {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t,"result"[z, t]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 500]
Manipulate[result, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {t, "result"[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]
```

Regards
Martin Wijaya

Answer (score 1):

I got your code to work (barring a couple syntax errors) by making `result` a function of `z` and `t`. I copied and pasted everything, but changed the final lines to:

```
result[z_, t_] = (ua[z, t] /. sol2) - (atm[z, t]) - (uw[z, t] /. sol2);
Plot3D[result[z, t], {z, zmin, zmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t, "result"[z, t]}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 500]
Manipulate[Plot[result[z, t], {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {t, "result"[z, t]}], {z, zmin, zmax}]
```

Comment: Wow...that is really nice...thanks

Comment: @MartinWijaya  The reason why this works and your original did not is that `Manipulate` localizes variables by default, which means the local `z` in the `Manipulate` is a different variable than the global `z` in `result`.  This solution gets around that by passing the local value in the function call.